# How to Track The Server Usage by The PID?

Tags: mysql, load

MySql is taking too much resource in one of my client's server. They are running a website developed in php. I have attached the screenshot below. Single process only taking too much resource.

I want to track that usage by the PID. its possible or not? if its possible please help me to track it.

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to somehow match a process ID from the operating system with a process ID in MySQL to determine which queries are consuming the greatest amount of resources?

Comment: Sounds like the real answer you want is how to I resolve understand the CPU utilization and work with the client to create an better application with less database CPU usage? Yes? Start by reading [this](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog), and including mysql information in this question.

Comment: Is there any way to place the limitation for a single process.?

Comment: "the limitation"? huh what limitation? You want to CPU limit it, sure its possible, and the client's PHP and its users will grind to a halt. Sorry, you're going to have to put an effort into learning the skills that your client already thinks you have.